# How to convert the text file to a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a text file which looks like this:

[text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uhwm.png)

[how i wanted my dataframe to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsC00.png)
I wanted to convert this text file to a dataframe using python so that my dataframe looks like the below:

Below is how my text file looks like:

Position of point (-61.871,29.65,25.77) (m)

Surge   Sway    Heave   Roll    Pitch   Yaw Z above wave
(m) (m) (m) (deg)   (deg)   (deg)   (m)

Significant amplitude   0.00782328954769049 0.887191653082297   1.16881344399239    0.257827560134168   0.0154829380891694  0.00148579427666974 2.04570391511689

3 hour max amplitude    0.0147399465957507  1.67502696999681    2.19181284530584    0.483311544566242   0.0290639450953993  0.00282780199111172 3.9685599858469

Average period (s)  8.91336838481586    8.65498715689717    9.52772136660616    9.57734175597055    9.39187976508895    7.71189985362629    5.81535607422081

and i want my dataframe to be:

Position of point(-61.871,29.65,25.77): Surge(m)  Sway(m) Heave(m) Roll(deg)

```
 Significant amplitude               0.007    0.887   1.16     0.257
 3 hour max amplitude                0.014    1.675   2.1918   0.483
  Average period (s)                 8.9133   8.654   9.527    9.577
```

how can i do that in python?

Comment: It looks like none of your data pasted to your question.  Try updating it.

Comment: can you copy/paste your data, instead of pasting images.

Comment: Hello my question has been updated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker has not shown any research done prior to asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `read_csv`.

```py
df = pandas.read_csv('example.txt', sep='\t')
```

You might need to try a double space instead of a `\t` too.